# Is there any way to set a minimum width on the viewport HTML

Tags: html, css, viewport

I know this question has been asked before; however, I have not seen any answers that have worked, at least for me. Here's what I mean:

When I write in my document head

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=700">`

It is like it has no effect what so ever it always just sizes to the device-width.

Same with this javascript solution which sets a minimum width when it sees that the screen width is smaller than the specified minimum width that I have seen as answers for this question.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

            var viewport = document.createElement("meta");
            viewport.setAttribute("name", "viewport");
            if (window.innerWidth < 700) {
                viewport.setAttribute("content", "width=700");
            } else {
                viewport.setAttribute("content", "width=device-width, initial-scale=1");
            }
            document.head.appendChild(viewport);

</script>
```

But still has no effect.

So what I have been doing is setting the minimum width on the html and body like this

```
html, body {
  min-width: 700px;
}
```

which I am happy to say works brilliantly but the reason I need the viewport element to have a minimum width of 700px is because I have `font-sizes` that are based on `vw` and `vh` (viewport width and viewport height) so the webpage has a minimum width of 700px but the font sizes continue to shrink according to the `device-width`.

So basically to sum it up at the end I will have a window width of say 400px, a page width of 700px, and a font size that is based off a 400px page width.

Please help! Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries Can't you just add styles into a media query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change the size of your document or body with viewport property. As you already know the viewport is a property of meta tag. Which means these properties are for your browser to follow not for your document. Example:

```
<meta name="author" content="John Doe">
```

Similarly viewport property would tell your browser that how much of your document should it show on the screen when it starts up. As described by [W3C](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-device-adapt/#the-atviewport-rule):

> This specification provides a way for an author to specify, in CSS,
>   the size, zoom factor, and orientation of the viewport that is used as
>   the base for the initial containing block.

meaning It specifies the width(and height) that should be assumed by the browser to show(scale) the web page(document) when It starts up(initial containing block).

This is legacy method when developing website for smaller device than **960px width** (browser assumed this default width) you would set the viewport so the browser would show you document properly.

Now a days best practice is to set this in your HTML:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

and manage everything else with css media queries so that your user doesn't have to zoom in or out due to bad scaling on small devices.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in a pure CSS!

```
@media screen and (max-width: 700px){ html,body {min-width:700px} }
```

Which reads, if browsers width is less than 700px, set html and body min-width to 700px.

Comment: Oh so do I have to set the font sizes inside `@media screen and (max-width: 700px) { ... }`

Comment: And you can not set the viewport to a minimum size?

Comment: You can not set devices width. If you wanted to do it you would need to be above the users device and have an axe to cut it to a width you need. This way you can only control CSS values which are applied (changed) if the width is less or more than x.